# How to add a custom field to the Django admin login page

Tags: python, django

To authenticate, 3 fields are needed:

- `user_id`
- `password`
- `account_id`

Each `account_id` defines an isolated space and the `user_id` is unique only inside its respective `account_id`.

I've created a custom backend authentication and I can authenticate successfully. The problem is that the login Django Admin form has `user_id` and `password` fields by default.

**I would like to add the `account_id` field in the original Django form template by only subclassing `AuthenticationForm`, is it possible?**

[image]

There's a similar question here but he's using a custom login template:
[Add custom field to Django Admin authentication form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63685570/add-custom-field-to-django-admin-authentication-form)

Existing code..

Model:

```
class HeliosUser(AbstractUser, DateModelBase):
    username = None
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    USERNAME_FIELD = "user_id"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["account_id", "role", "email"]

    objects = HeliosUserManager()

    email = models.EmailField()
    account_id = models.ForeignKey(
        "agent.Agent",
        on_delete=models.RESTRICT,
    )
    ...
```

Backend:

```
class SettingsBackend(BaseBackend):
    def authenticate(
        self, request, user_id=None, account_id=None, password=None, **kwargs
    ):
        try:
            user = HeliosUser.objects.get(
                user_id=user_id, account_id=account_id
            )
        except HeliosUser.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        if user.check_password(password):
            return user
        return None

    def get_user(self, user_id, account_id):
        try:
            return HeliosUser.objects.get(
                user_id=user_id, account_id=account_id
            )
        except HeliosUser.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Admin site:

```
class HeliosUserAdmin(admin.AdminSite):
    site_title = "Helios Administration"
    site_header = "Helios Administration"
    index_title = "Helios Administration"
    login_form = HeliosAuthenticationForm


admin_site = HeliosUserAdmin()
```

Authentication form:

```
class HeliosAuthenticationForm(AuthenticationForm):
    account_id = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Agent.objects.all())
```

Thank's in advance!